# Output matrix in the user command concindexi in Stata

Tags: stata

This is in regard to the user command `Concindexi` in `Stata` which is used for the computation of [concentration index](http://siteresources.worldbank.org/INTPAH/Resources/Publications/459843-1195594469249/HealthEquityCh8.pdf). The definition and details regarding `Concindexi` are not necessary for answering the question below.

To explain the problem, I use the auto data from `Stata` library (again the function is not meant for this type of data, rather it is used for household data).

The following is the syntax:

```
concindexi [varlist] [if] [in] [weight] [ , welfarevar(varname) format(format)
    curve convenient clean }
```

I use `rank` of `weight` as `welfare variable`

```
sysuse auto
egen weightrank=rank( weight)
sort weightrank
```

The concentration index for `price` is given as

```
concindexi  price,  welfarevar(weightrank)
```

Output (so far no problem)

```
Concentration index estimation using the covariance/formula method

Final matrice of Concentration Indices on Individual (Micro) Data.

             CIF      CISEF
price  .14318137  .02934612


CIF :   Concentration index using formula/covariance method
CIC :   Concentration index using convenient regression method
CISEF : Standard errors of the concentration index using formula/covariance method
CISEC : Standard errors of the concentration index convenient regression method
```

Here is the problem: if I repeat the same command with the same variable `price` (without restarting `Stata`) ,it will now give 2*2 by matrix (the results get accumulated).

```
concindexi  price,  welfarevar(weightrank)
```

Output:

```
Concentration index estimation using the covariance/formula method



Final matrice of Concentration Indices on Individual (Micro) Data.


             CIF      CISEF
price  .14318137  .02934612
price  .14318137  .02934612


CIF :   Concentration index using formula/covariance method
CIC :   Concentration index using convenient regression method
CISEF : Standard errors of the concentration index using formula/covariance method
CISEC : Standard errors of the concentration index convenient regression method
```

If I repeat the same command again, I have 3 by 2 matrix.

```
concindexi  price,  welfarevar(weightrank)

Concentration index estimation using the covariance/formula method



Final matrice of Concentration Indices on Individual (Micro) Data.


             CIF      CISEF
price  .14318137  .02934612
price  .14318137  .02934612
price  .14318137  .02934612


CIF :   Concentration index using formula/covariance method
CIC :   Concentration index using convenient regression method
CISEF : Standard errors of the concentration index using formula/covariance method
CISEC : Standard errors of the concentration index convenient regression method
```

Normally, we would expect 1*2 matrix irrespective of how many times the command is executed while in the same session of `Stata` [Take for instance the command `regress`]. The problem, however, disappears if we restart `Stata` each time.

This problem is not serious for the example mentioned here. However, if the number of variable is large (it can accommodate large variables) and/or if I have to bootstrap, the problem becomes very serious. For example, in my data with 13 variables and 20000 observations, replication [in bootstrapping] was possible only for 29 times but for 2 variables, corresponding number was 100. Any idea to fix the problem would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `concindexi` is a user-written command (not function) available from SSC.

In Stata commands and functions are quite distinct.

In Stata discussions it is helpful to indicate where commands come from; that is certainly strong advice on Statalist (see http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/resources/statalist-faq/) and it seems a fair request for other forums.

The solution is documented. There is an option `clean` to `concindexi`, which erases matrices and scalars previously created by the program. Presumably the author built in the accumulation of results as a feature he (and possibly his users) wanted. As a matter of Stata programming style that is unusual behaviour. We could discuss how far it is good style, but as a way is provided to overwrite it this comes down to personal taste. Evidently you are surprised by the behaviour, and I would be too, as it is only documented indirectly through this `clean` option.

So strictly it is quite incorrect that "definition and details regarding `concindexi` are not necessary for answering the question". The answer hinges on looking inside the code and  reading its documentation, and the behaviour raises no generic Stata question.

Comment: @ Nick: I agree with you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @ Nick: I have replaced the function with command in `question`.